# How to use LocalStorage and SQLite Databases with Phonegap/Cordova?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I'm new to using Phonegap and I'm trying to make an app that will store arrays and setting preferences when the app is closed. I am thinking of adding a cloud saving feature so they could save the data to either their Google drive or my own cloud and I'm thinking I should use a SQLite database for that? The problem is that I know very little about SQLite databases and how to use them in JavaScript. If I chose not to use the cloud feature, do you think just using LocalStorage will be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. This creates the database table when the page loads.

```
var db;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("DiaryDB", "1.0", "DiaryDB", 200000);
    db.transaction(createDB, transaction_error, createDB_success);
}

function createDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DiaryTab');
    var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DiaryTab ("
    + "EntryID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + "EntryDate TEXT, " + "EntryTitle TEXT, " + "EntryContent Text"
    + ")";
    tx.executeSql(sql);
}

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
    alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function createDB_success(){
    alert("Database and Table Created");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And this inserts a new record. Just change the SQL statement to do updates and deletion. Populate entryDate, entryTitle, and entryContent with the values you want to insert.

```
function insertRecord(tx){
        var insertString = "INSERT INTO DiaryTab (entryDate, entryTitle, entryContent) VALUES ('" 
        + entryDate + "','" 
        + entryTitle + "','" 
        + entryContent + "')";
        tx.executeSql(insertString);
    }

function saveEntry(){
    entryDate = $("#date").val();
    entryTitle = $("#title").val();
    entryContent = $("#contents").val();
    db.transaction(insertRecord, transaction_error, insert_success);
}

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
        alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function insert_success(){
    alert("New Entry Inserted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is ***NOT*** guaranteed to be persistent, especially on iOS. You should not store anything in `localStorage` that is not something that can be easily recreated or downloaded in case the data disappears.

There are various storage options, of which using a SQLite plugin is only one. None of them will implement cloud sync (beyond getting backed up by iCloud on iDevices). You'll need to handle that yourself. You *might* consider [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com) (not affiliated in any way), but there are lots of other options out there as well. You'll need to consider the security and privacy implications of this as well, and make those clear in your privacy statement to your end users.